# About android LVL'response code

Tags: android, android-lvl

i'm implementing the licensing service in one of my apps. No matter what response code i set to the test account,it always invokes the allow() function.Even the phone without the test account.

But i thought the phone without the test account should receive the NOT_LISCENED reponse code 
at anytime.Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LVL test response will be sent back to a phone with your publisher account as well as to any with test accounts.

Comment: But what response code should a phone without my publisher account or test account receive?

Comment: It should receive NOT_LICENSED. Is the app already published or is it in draft?

Comment: It is uploaded but not published.

Comment: What happens if you change the test response to NOT_LICENSED?

Comment: Also get the LICENSED response code. I think something must be wrong in my code.

Comment: Sure sounds like it. It might help if you posted it. :)

Comment: Code too long and not well-formed,i need to check it by myself.Thank you very very much also. :)

Comment: HAHAHA，I  get the reason.   "Additionally, as noted above, applications that are in draft mode (in other words, applicaitons that have been uploaded but have never been published) will return LICENSED for all users, even if not listed as a test user. Since the application has never been offered for download, it is assumed that any users running it must have obtained it from an authorized channel for testing purposes."